# Search pdf page using PdfJs & PDFFindController constructor

Tags: typescript, systemjs, pdf.js

I am displaying pdf documents using [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js). Now I want to be able to search for text within a pdf document.
There are some examples on how to do this, but they do not work, because the constructor for `PDFFindController` cannot be found.

Displaying the document worked fine using

```
let loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);
loadingTask.promise.then((pdf: any) => { /* display code here */ }
```

But when I try to create a PDFFindController as suggested in this [Example](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/components/simpleviewer.js#L58) it fails.

```
new pdfjsLib.PDFFindController();
```

The error in Firefox shows as:

```
TypeError: pdfjs_dist_1.default.PDFFindController is not a constructor
```

I am not sure how to proceed from here, since it looks similar to the example and others I found on stackoverflow.

When I print the library object to the console it is not showing `PDFFindController` or even `PDFViewer` on this object, so I could imagine that `PDFFindController` requires a different library file, but the docs aren't to clear which file or how to import it using systemjs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing `pdfjsLib.PDFFindController()` by `pdfjsViewer.PDFFindController()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pdf.js search method. you should call it like this:

```
PDFViewerApplication.findController.executeCommand("find" + evt.type, {
query: evt.query,
phraseSearch: evt.phraseSearch,
caseSensitive: evt.caseSensitive,
entireWord: evt.entireWord,
highlightAll: evt.highlightAll,
findPrevious: evt.findPrevious });
```

just replace your search key with "evt.query".

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this, and it took me forever to solve this. Here you go. You are getting that error because PDFLinkService() is not a function of PDFjsLib, you need to call that from PdfJsViewer.

Try this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.5.207/web/pdf_viewer.js"></script>

const PdfJsViewer = window['pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer'];
 const pdfLinkService = new pdfjsViewer.PDFLinkService({
  eventBus,
});
```

Rest you can check here: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/components/simpleviewer.js